# "makes pointer from integer without a cast" in Cocos2D for iPhone

Tags: iphone, methods, cocos2d-iphone, selector, arguments

I'm using an action in cocos2D that calls a method and passes a BOOL as an parameter.

I get the warning: "Passing argument 3 of 'actionWithTarget:selector:data:' makes pointer from integer without a cast" with this line:

```
id actionCharacterReaction = [CCCallFuncND actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(characterReaction : data:) data:flipChar];
```

I've tried:

```
id actionCharacterReaction = [CCCallFuncND actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(characterReaction : data:) data:(BOOL)flipChar];
```

My method looks like this:

```
-(void) characterReaction:(id)sender data:(BOOL)flipChar {
    *code stuff inside*
}
```

It still seems to work fine. I'm just annoyed by the warning. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are going to need to wrap you `flipChar` in an `NSNumber` to pass it as a reference properly. When using selectors you can not pass primitive types directly.

```
id actionCharacterReaction = [CCCallFuncND actionWithTarget:self
                              selector:@selector(characterReaction : data:) 
                                  data:[[NSNumber numberWithBool:flipChar] retain]];
...

-(void) characterReaction:(id)sender data:(NSNumber*)flipChar {
    BOOL fc = [flipChar boolValue];
    *code stuff inside*
    [flipChar release]; //Retained in call to CCCallFuncND
}
```

Edit: after briefly looking at the documentation it looks like it takes a `void*`. Since `void*` can be any object, not just an Objective-C object, so you will likely need to manually retain and release the number. Code above is updated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having does not have to do with your `characterReaction:data:` method, but rather, with the `actionWithTarget:selector:data` method.

You are passing in what is, I assume, a BOOL as the `data:` argument, but the method expects a pointer (the declaration has is as `void *`). You should change your method to follow that. Try passing in an object, and making your method accept an object.

Answer (score 0):

The `data:` arg expects an object, and `BOOL` is a simple value type. To effectively pass a `BOOL`, you need to create an object that will then be converted back to `BOOL` as part of the process of calling the selector you specified. You need to create an object that, when converted to `BOOL`, contains any value to indicate `YES`, and that's `nil` for `NO`. You can create an `NSNumber` for `YES`:

`id actionCharacterReaction = [CCCallFuncND actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(characterReaction : data:) data:(flipChar ? [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] : nil)];`